# Making domain data available to WCF behavior

Tags: wcf, wcf-behaviour

In my application, I have a value ("BusinessUnit") which I want to add into every request to a web-service. One way of doing this would be to write a WCF behaviour, which would insert the value for me.

However, the one part I am not clear on is how I can get this value from my application and into the behaviour.

To illustrate my question, here is how I might implement it.

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    string businessUnit = //How do I set this to a value known by the client?
    MessageHeader<string> header = 
        new MessageHeader<string>(businessUnit);
    request.Headers.Add(
        header.GetUntypedHeader("Business Unit", "http://mywebsite.com"));
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If this value is the same for all calls, then you can consider using a static variable for it. If it varies per call, you can use the operation context to add it (and even skipping the behavior), as shown below

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(...);
using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    MessageHeader<string> header = new MessageHeader<string>(businessUnit);
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header.GetUntypedHeader("Business Unit", "http://mywebsite.com"));
    client.MakeServiceCall();
}
```

If it's something that varies per *group* of calls, you can consider passing it to the behavior when you create the client, and then the behavior can pass it to the inspector it creates:

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(...);
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyBehavior(businessUnit));
client.MakeServiceCall1();
client.MakeServiceCall2();
client.MakeServiceCall3();
```

Comment: Thanks for that - the 3rd way is sort of doable. I was hoping to set the behaviour in the web.config though, to avoid changing any code. For the 1st way - the value will be different for all calls. For the 2nd way, I want to use a behaviour so that I can do this across 50+ web-services.